# Radial lemmas of Strauss, Berestycki, and Lions

Tags: sobolev-spaces

A famous radial lemma of Strauss states that

> **Theorem** (Strauss). For $n \geq 2$, every radial function $u \in W^{1,2}(\mathbf R^n)$ is almost
>   everywhere equal to a function $U$, continuous for $x \ne 0$ and such that
>   $$|U(x)| \lesssim |x|^{(1-n)/2}\|u\|_{W^{1,2}(\mathbf R^n)}$$
>   for $|x| \gg1$.

Berestycki and Lions give a similar result for the homogeneous Sobolev space $\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)$ which is the closure of $C_0^\infty (\mathbf R^n)$ under the norm
$$\|u\|_{\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)}=\int_{\mathbf R^n} |\nabla u|^2 dx.$$

> **Theorem** (Berestycki and Lions). For $n \geq 3$, every radial function $u \in \mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)$ is almost everywhere equal to a function $U$, continuous for $x \ne 0$ and such that
>   $$|U(x)| \lesssim |x|^{(2-n)/2}\|u\|_{\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)}$$
>   for $|x| \gg1$.

Since $C_0^\infty (\mathbf R^n)$ is dense in both $W^{1,2}(\mathbf R^n)$ and $\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)$, to prove the above two results, it suffices to consider the case $u \in C_0^\infty (\mathbf R^n)$. What I am interested in is the following: if we use a density argument, we would expect from the Berestycki and Lions lemma the inequality 
$$|u(x)| \lesssim |x|^{(2-n)/2}\|u\|_{\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)}$$
for $|x| \gg1$, where $u \in \mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)$. However, it does not seem to be true because, as far as I know, the constant 1 function belongs to $\mathcal D^{1,2}_0(\mathbf R^n)$ whereas the inequality fails. Hence it is natural to ask when went wrong with the density argument. At least I do not see this is a problem with the Strauss lemma because the constant 1 function does not belong to $W^{1,2}(\mathbf R^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any of these interesting results for radial functions, but I don't think $1\in\mathcal D_0^{1,2}$. Suppose that $u_k \in C_c^\infty$ and converge to $u$ in $\mathcal D_0^{1,2}$. Then recall Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev (Theorem 1 of 5.6 in Evans) which says that for  a constant only depending on the dimension $n$, since $(u_k-u_m)$ is compactly supported,

$$ \|u_k - u_m \|_{L^{2*}} \le \|\nabla u_k - \nabla u_m\|_{L^2}$$
where $\frac1{2*} := \frac12 - \frac1n$.
So in particular $u_k$ converges in the Banach space $L^{2*}$, so the limit $u\neq 1$. This shows actually $\mathcal D_0^{1,2}$ is continuously embedded in $L^{2*}$.